# How do I make my own custom UIColor's other than the preset ones?

Tags: ios, iphone, uicolor

I want to make my own RGB colors that are `UIColors` and that I could use just like `UIColor blackColor` or any other.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can write your own method for UIColor class using categories.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface UIColor(NewColor)
+(UIColor *)MyColor;
@end

#import "UIColor-NewColor.h"
@implementation UIColor(NewColor)
+(UIColor *)MyColor {
     return [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0-1.0 green:0.0-1.0 blue:0.0-1.0 alpha:1.0f];
}
```

By this way, you create a new color and now you can call it like

```
[UIColor MyColor];
```

You can also implement this method to obtain random color.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using a similar solution but I have to called something like: [[UIColor alloc] MyColor] for it to work. Is there a way to not have to allocate it?

Comment: @adjwilli Make sure you are using a `+` in front of the method declaration, not a `-`. This will make it a class method vs. an instance method.

Answer (score 27):

I needed to define a couple of custom colors for use in several places in an app - but the colours are specific to that app.  I thought about using categories, but didn't want to have extra files to include every time.  I've therefore created a couple of static methods in my App delegate.

In MyAppDelegate.h

```
+ (UIColor*)myColor1;
```

In MyAppDelegate.m

```
+ (UIColor*)myColor1 {  
return [UIColor colorWithRed:26.0f/255.0f green:131.0f/255.0f blue:32.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];  
}
```

I have a method per color, or you could do a single method and add a parameter.

I can then use it anywhere in the app like this:

```
myView.backgroundColor = [MyAppDelegate myColor1];
```

I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: App delegates want to be good. But then they learn about things. They learn about things they have no business knowing.

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 3**

Creating a Swift extension allows you to define your own custom colors and use them just like the built in colors.

*UIColor+CustomColor.swift*

```
import UIKit

extension UIColor {

    class var customGreen: UIColor {
        let darkGreen = 0x008110
        return UIColor.rgb(fromHex: darkGreen)
    }

    class func rgb(fromHex: Int) -> UIColor {

        let red =   CGFloat((fromHex & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 0xFF
        let green = CGFloat((fromHex & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 0xFF
        let blue =  CGFloat(fromHex & 0x0000FF) / 0xFF
        let alpha = CGFloat(1.0)

        return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.customGreen
```

[image]

Comment: This needs to be at the top of the answers list.

Answer (score 8):

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:51.0 / 255.0, green:0.0, blue:153.0 / 255.0];
```

As long as you use a floating point value in your division you don't have to cast anything. Make sure you use floating point values. For example: `33 / 255 = 0`. Which will become black.

Answer (score 7):

There are a couple of ways to create a color.

I prefer to use the RGB method.  If you use the RGB values, divide them by 255 (I do not remember why, but I know you need to do it).

```
float rd = 225.00/255.00;
float gr = 177.00/255.00;
float bl = 140.00/255.00;
[label setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:rd green:gr blue:bl alpha:1.0]];
```

Hope this helps.....

Comment: The red, green, blue, and alpha values that are passed to the constructor need to be between 0.0 and 1.0.

Answer (score 3):

For Swift:

```
let swiftColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 165/255, blue: 233, alpha: 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [initWithRed:green:blue:alpha:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006892-CH3-SW5) or [colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006892-CH3-SW11).

For example:

```
// create new autoreleased UIColor object named "myColor"
UIColor *myColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5f green:0.5f blue:0.5f alpha:1.0f];

// create new retained UIColor object named "myColor2"
UIColor *myColor2 = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.5f green:0.5f blue:0.5f alpha:1.0f];
```

Comment: But would that allow me to say something like:
UIColor *orangeColor = [UIColor alloc] initWithRed:greenLblue:alpha:];
and then use it later?

Comment: Yes, with the correct syntax. I added code examples. Make sure to properly manage the memory: if you use the class convenience constructor, then you need to retain the color object or set a retained property to it.